# How do they show time travel, spells and the Sorting Hat on stage?

Tags: harry-potter, the-cursed-child

I couldn't fly to the London to see *Harry Potter and the Cursed Child* play (availability of tickets is another issue). Also, there's no video recording available (so, I want to yell at J. K. Rowling who disrespected millions of fans across the globe). I just read its script book (special rehearsal edition). Also, I have never seen a professional stage play in my life, so my imagination isn't working regarding several things.

Well, flights could happen using rope, but what about time travel scene?

> ALBUS takes the Time-Turner from SCORPIUS - he presses down upon it and the Time-Turner begins to vibrate, and **then explodes into a storm of movement.**
>
> And with it the stage starts to transform. The two boys look at it.
>
> And there is a giant whoosh of light. A smash of noise.
>
> **And time stops. And then it turns over, thinks a bit, and begins spooling backwards, slow at first...**
>
> **And then it speeds up.**

And, spells?

> DELPHI unleashes a bolt from her hand.

And, sorting hat?

> **The SORTING HAT walks through the students** who spring into their houses.
>
> It becomes quickly apparent **he's approaching ROSE**, who is tense as she awaits her fate.

(Sorting Hat was played by a human who also played Hagrid; I just want to know how sorting procedure happened)

Can you please explain how these things exactly happened on stage in case you watched the play in real?

Comment: Smoke and mirrors are traditional.

Comment: @Valorum I believe you are from London. Did you watch the play?

Comment: I'm further North and have little interest in coining out £100 to see the am-dram version of what should have been a film

Comment: @Valorum * of cheap fanfiction that should've never happened.

Comment: Ability to go and see the Cursed Child and inclination to go and see the Cursed Child cannot be read as being the same thing...

Comment: The question "Did you watch the play?" cannot be read as requiring "ability to see the play" instead of "inclination to see the play."  It only asks *if the action was taken at all, or not.* In Val's case, the answer is clearly "no" - an answer which he gives *implicitly* by explaining why he would be *disinclined* to subject himself to such an activity.

Comment: @Steve-O - I have the ability, but not the desire. I might watch it if it was in town, and was modestly priced.

Comment: Don't yell at JK. First it's not her play. Second, this is the way plays work. They are designed for stage, and the point is for people to come and see them on stage. It's pretty unsurprising that the authors haven't released a video, for the same reason that the movies weren't released on YouTube.

Comment: Also I think it's very reasonably priced. I saw it for £100 for both parts - like five hours of play. When the cheapest tickets for Aladdin are like £75 for half the entertainment. And a Harry Potter play could charge whatever they like and millions would still pay it. They have made it quite competitive really.

Comment: @DJClayworth When she decided to put Harry Potter on stage, she did wrong. Harry Potter type globally famous franchise shouldn't have been treated like this. It's no longer a Shakespeare's world. She indeed disrespected Harry Potter fans.

Comment: @user931 - Or brought a whole new generation to the theatre like she did to reading.

Comment: @ThruGog The problem is with distribution to the global community. As casts are definite which is important (it's not like circus), the play can't be run simultaneously across globe, not to mention that casts won't remain same after years: They may die, lose their ability to perform or grow old. Theatre stage play is not a very good media to present a story for a globally successful franchise.

Comment: @user931 - The original cast are already able to move on soon if they want to, but that shouldn't really matter. It'll be in Broadway by the end of next year and the book is out. And eventually it'll travel. I can see your point but I still think it's better as it is than just non-existent.

Comment: There is a video version available if one is willing to venture to certain sections of the internet. It's not very good quality though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I saw it very recently. The Sorting Hat is stylised as a man holding a hat - I say stylised because the hat isn't designed like the film or even book one - it's like a bowler hat. He holds it over people's heads and speaks as the hat. He also has moments where he acts like a narrator.

The 'time turning' effects are very clever. There are clocks around the place and they revolve in a predictable fashion with various sound and light effects - then using clever light effects the entire stage and much of the theatre appears to ripple. It's very impressive. People really "wowed!" audibly the first few times. All of the panelling and arches around the place appear to ripple in a very realistic way. I think the effect is similar to the sort of thing used when at Disneyland and they project light onto their 'castles' as part of their nighttime firework displays. This can also be seen in other events, for example Buckingham Palace has had similar light displays.

Spells are a mixed bag. Several spells are very clever including Harry tidying his desk - all the papers leap into neat piles from the mess they were in. I'm not sure how they achieved this; it definitely looked like more than papers on strings due to the complexity. It matched the flourish of the wand very well. People transform before your eyes when they take Polyjuice - I think the actors used their cloaks combined with holes in the stage so that for a brief period you have two actors standing behind one another within the cloak and as they writhe to 'sell' the effects of the potion, one head goes in and the other almost instantly comes out. It's very impressive - they must be wearing extra-voluminous cloaks at this point and it must take a great deal of rehearsal. These are actors, not Cirque du Soleil contortionists! Wizards and are instantly sucked into the Ministry telephone box entrance which I believe involved quick changes from actors to cloaks with nothing in them suspended like puppets, then sucked in. The speed of this is impressive as there is a seamless change from actor to empty cloak, which must be suspended from the eaves... then sucked in to a different spot.
Others like Avada Kedavra are just jets of flame behind the wands.

Comment: I don't think you need spoilers here :D

Comment: @Gallifreyan - No. Massive overkill

Comment: Are you sure? Some people will have read the script and may want to see it and not want the experience spoiled.

Comment: @ThruGog - Anyone reading the question will know that answers will have spoilers for the effects.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FloatingClocks

Comment: Were smartphones allowed in the theatre?

Comment: @user931 - Certainly.

Comment: @ThruGog Still nobody recorded anything? I didn't find a single clip on YouTube.

Comment: @user931 - They use comic reminders from the actors to turn them off before each part starts and there is the clear suggestion that they can confiscate them. But people have paid lots of money and waited AGES so I don't think anyone is interested in breaking the rules once in. And there's a lot of promotion to #keepthesecrets

Comment: @user931- The people who record these things typically don't post them to YouTube or other parts of the public scene.

Answer (score 4):

Here are how the three scenes you refer to played out.

- **Time Travel** (Part 1, Act 2, Scene 6)

  > [image: CC Time Turner 1.2.6]
- **Rose being sorted** (Part 1, Act 1, Scene 4)

  > [image: CC sorting 1.1.4]
- **Delphi casting Incendio** (Part 2, Act 4, Scene 11)

  > [image: CC Incendio 2.4.11]